# Help/advice on simulating paint drip over background movie clip

Tags: particles, physics, fluid-simulation, dynamic-paint

I'm working with a movie clip, and am trying to have a blue paint fluid slowly drip down from the sky (out of camera view), obstacle over some steps, then finally make it pool itself toward the viewer, within some specified *XYZ Coordinates.*

I've been setting up a `Domain Box` of different *XYZ lengths*, and an `Inflow Object` as a **Fluid Simulation** which seems to be working okay, but I'm not entirely clear if I should instead be working with a combination of *Particles* & *Dynamic Paint*, or some other combination for this job.

Indeed, first time really working with any of these physics simulations, so any insights or workflow tips for this specific situation would be deeply appreciated. Including a quick, very rough render of where I'm at in my test set-up, which hopefully will illuminate what I'm trying to do. Thanks much ahead.

[image: Quick render/test set up]

Comment: Do you have a specific problem or question?

Comment: @Gunslinger, I thought I was being fairly specific, but perhaps not. With the parameters I outlined in my initial paragraph, I'm wondering if someone can provide some thoughts or a brief walk-thru of how they might go about doing what I wish to do.